# File upload not working in selenium base because [type="file"] not present for the element

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

I want to upload a file using selenium Base, but the problem is that the dom [type="file"] is not present for the element for which I want to upload a file.

Below is my dom image for reference
[image]

Neew help to upload file anyhow

Comment: this is a `post` action and not a `selenium` action, therefore use selenium to get the `action` url and do the upload using `requests.post`

Comment: @thethiny I have tried using python but not working, receiving `The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.` and this is I tried `url = "https://stage.fieldtofinish.jobs/order/upload/survey_file?order=1000196318&address=TESTOUR"
        with open("C:/Users/Krupal/OneDrive/Desktop/file.txt", 'rb') as f:
            files = {'upload_file': f.read()}

        values = {'DB': 'photcat', 'OUT': 'csv', 'SHORT': 'short'}

        r = requests.post(url, files=files)`

Comment: @thethiny can you help me to how to do?

Comment: The url needs to come from the page, not hardcoded, so if you refresh the page it will change. Press F12 go to network, upload the file and see how it's used.

Comment: @thethiny i have used URL which is called in the network tab when I upload file manually